# What is the cheapest way to execute a LINQ-Query immediately

Tags: .net, vb.net, performance, linq

This question came into my mind while generating sample data for a SO-answer.
I don't like the verbose way of adding DataRows one by one via `Tbl.Rows.Add`, so i've created this pseudo LINQ query that does nothing but adding rows implicitely:

```
Private Function GetData() As DataTable
    Dim years = {"2010/2009", "2009/2008", "2008/2007", "2007/2006", "2006/2005", "2005/2004", "2004/2003"}
    Dim tbl = New DataTable
    tbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Year"))
    ' adds DataRows to the DataTable, need Count to execute the query '
    Dim c = (From y In years Select tbl.Rows.Add(y)).Count 
    Return tbl
End Function
```

As you can see i don't need the result of the query at all, it's only purpose is to iterate and call `DataTable.Rows.Add`. So the result is already available in the DataTable itself and not needed from the query.

Admittedly this question is somewhat hyphotetical because there would not be a big difference in using f.e. `ToList` and normally a query's purpose is to return something.

But anyway, what's the cheapest way(in terms of memory consumption, execution time) to execute a LINQ query when only the execution and not the result matters?

**Edit**: Ok, thisquestion was a quick-shot and a chicken-and-egg problem. I wanted to reduce 20 lines of code to a single line but noticed that i need some kind of DataSource for the LINQ-Query. Therefor i've created the Array. But at this point i could have simply used a for-each loop as well to add the DataRows.

**Conclusion**: Use a LINQ-Query for what it's for: a *query*. Then this question is pointless since there is no *cheapest* way but only that which returns the correct result.

Comment: Wouldn't a `foreach` yield more readable code?  This looks like a case of _using LINQ just because I can_.  This is also somewhat anti-LINQ because it has side effects.

Comment: LINQ does not guarantee any side effects to occur: For example, LINQ-to-objects could be implemented in a way where `Count` ignores any any `Select` projections, since they do not change the number of elements. So, you are relying on an undocumented behavior, which could (theoretically) change any time.

Comment: Your core question should be answered with, _you shouldn't do that_. You're trying to substitute a projection for an action. You then force a materialization to enforce your side effect (the intended action).

Comment: +1 for a SO answer being the inspiration of this question.

Comment: @Marc: Yes you're right. This example unfortunately is not as good as i thought. First i've created that DataTable without a loop by simply creating new rows(`tbl.NewRow`), filling them and finally adding them to the DataTable. So i asked myself if there is no one-liner for this 20 lines of code. Hence i've created that array. At this point i simply could have used a for-each as well. I've missed that point after i've created the LINQ query.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd just rewrite it as a `foreach`:

```
For Each y As String in years
    tbl.Rows.Add(y)
Next
```

It's much more clear what your intention is this way, and it executes right away.

Comment: You are right. My first approach was not to use `tbl.Rows.Add` but creating the DataRow from `Dim row=tbl.NewRow`,`row("Year")=y`,`tbl.Rows.Add(row)`. That's what i've meant with verbose. In this case i could simply use the for each as well. Now there is a lack of a good example.

Answer (score 2):

I'd be more tempted to use a `List(Of T)`:

```
Dim years As New List(Of String) From {"2010/2009", "2009/2008", "2008/2007", "2007/2006", "2006/2005", "2005/2004", "2004/2003"}

years.ForEach(Sub(y) tbl.Rows.Add(y))
```

It's all subjective though, loops are probably most clear for these one liners.

Comment: Ok that would be a reasonable use of the `ForEach()` method.

Comment: Not being a vb.net guy, I was unaware of the lambda version of `ForEach`. I like this way more than my own answer.

Comment: @tzaman for a test rig? I would possibly agree. For production code, I think your `foreach` wins every time.