# Executing LINQ expression

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am trying to fill my datatable using LINQ expression below , this works fine but feels like a hack. Is there a better way to do this ?

```
var Records = <Dictionary object with some data.>

DataTable objDataTable = null;
objDataTable.Columns.Add("Column1", typeof (string));
objDataTable.Columns.Add("Column2", typeof (string));

// Have to perform .Count() to execute the linq expression in order to 
// add datarows in datatable

Records.Keys.Select(rec => objDataTable.Rows.Add(new object[] {rec, Records[rec]})).Count();
```

As you can see above I have to to `.Count()` at the end in order to execute the statement. Earlier I was doing `.ToArray()` but then I thought `.Count()` would be cheaper.

Either way this does not feel very readable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the cheapest way to execute a LINQ-Query immediately](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010639/what-is-the-cheapest-way-to-execute-a-linq-query-immediately) -- the similarities are impressive...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - just use a `foreach` loop which is perfectly readable and suited for this:

```
foreach(var rec in Records.Keys)
{
    objDataTable.Rows.Add(new object[] {rec, Records[rec]});
}
```

Just because you *can* use Linq does not mean you should *always* be compelled to do so - especially if you have code with side effects.

Comment: This was my default implementation..was just trying to see if there is anything else available that I might be missing

Answer (score 1):

Use a `ForEach` instead:

```
Records.Keys.ForEach(rec => objDataTable.Rows.Add(new object[] {rec, Records[rec]}));
```

Comment: its a Dictionary<string,string>...not allowing me to perform ForEach like this on Keys

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you always look up the value for each key you iterate over, I'd say just enumerate the dictionary itself:

```
foreach(var kvp in Records)
{
    objDataTable.Rows.Add(new object[] {kvp.Key, kvp.Value});
}
```

Here `kvp` is a `KeyValuePair<string, string>`. To my eye this makes it clearer that you want to do something with every *entry* in the dictionary.