# How to break link between source collection and LINQ result

Tags: c#, linq

For example, I Have such code:

```
IEnumerable<RSuspectOperationCode> distinctCodes = this.Distinct(); // "this" is some collection
this.Clear()
distinctCodes.Count();
```

As LINQ is deferred execution query - Count gives us 0. I'm interesting - is there a approach to get a distinct collection with in-place result calculation and breaking link between source and result collection, that clearing source collection won't affect result collection?

My workaround:

```
    List<RSuspectOperationCode> distinctCodes = new List<RSuspectOperationCode>();
    distinctCodes.AddRange(this.Distinct(comparer));
    this.Clear();
    distinctCodes.Count();
```

But, I wonder, is there more elegant/shorter way?

Comment: Sorry, typed code by memory, mistakened

Comment: possible duplicate of [Force Linq to not delay execution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064043/force-linq-to-not-delay-execution)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call some method that will evaluate the query.  In your case, calling `ToArray` or `ToList` will do what you want by evaluating the query and placing the result in a new array or `List<RSuspectOperationCode>`.  That new list will not be affected by any changes you make to the original list.

Note that a lot of people use `ToList` by default, which is wrong.  Regardless of the situation, if you don't intend the change the length of a list then you should use an array rather than a collection.  That means that `ToArray` should be your default choice and only use `ToList` when you specifically need a `List<T>`.  It's not a major issue but you may as well do things the right way.

Comment: *That means that ToArray should be your default choice* I believe `ToArray` can end up with an extra memory allocation than ToList, because an array has to be the exact size of the collection it represents whereas a List separates its capacity from its size. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16323412/242520

Comment: Yes, I know how `List<T>` is implemented. `ToList` and `ToArray` both follow the same allocation pattern up until the very end, in which case `ToList` is done but if `ToArray` has allocated an array that's bigger than necessary it has to allocate *another* array of the correct size and copy everything into it. So by using `ToList` you skip that overhead.

Answer (score 1):

call `.ToList()` whenever you want it to be executed immediately.

```
var distinctCodes= this.Distinct().ToList();

this.Clear();

var c1 = this.Count(); // 0

var c2 = distinctCodes.Count(); // eg. 100
```

Comment: This won't have deferred execution for distinct.

Comment: @user3246354 He didn't ask for deferred execution on his distinct list. He just wants a list of distinct items.

Comment: I was refering to in-place result calculation in "is there a approach to get a distinct collection with in-place result calculation and breaking link between source and result collection, that clearing source collection won't affect result collection?"

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling ToList after Distinct, call it before so you have deferred execution in your distinct list:

```
var distinctCodes = this.ToList().Distinct();
```

Answer (score 0):

I use to add `.ToList()` at the end of a Linq expression to get the enumeratio done, and to have a copy of the collection.

In your case,

```
... = this.Distinct().ToList()
```

should do the trick.